# Can not stub private element in WCT

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, sinon, web-component-tester

Using Polymer 1 and Web component tester... testing in shady dom on chrome.

In WCT, trying to stub spToast.display() with `stub('sp-toast', { display: ()=> {} });` but I get error with `Attempted to wrap undefined property display as function`.... what I am doing wrong?

The reason why I am trying to stub it is because I get `spToast.display is not a function` when the test runs the code base.

original code:

```
 showAgeWarning: function() {
    var spApp = Polymer.dom(document).querySelector('sp-app');
    var spToast = Polymer.dom(spApp.root).querySelector('sp-toast');

    var msg = "foo"
    spToast.display('information', msg);
  },
```

test code:

```
<test-fixture id="sp-veteran">
  <template>
    <h2>edit veteran</h2>
    <sp-app>
      <sp-toast></sp-toast>
      <sp-veteran>
      </sp-veteran>
    </sp-app>
  </template>
</test-fixture>

    setup(function() {
      replace('sp-app').with('fake-sp-app');
      replace('sp-ajax').with('fake-sp-ajax');
      stub('sp-value-dropdown', { setInvalidState: (state)=> {} });
      myEl = fixture('sp-veteran');
    });

  test('it should validate the veteran', function() {
      var spApp = Polymer.dom(myEl.root).querySelector('sp-app');
      var spToast = Polymer.dom(spApp.root).querySelector('sp-toast');
      sinon.stub(spToast, 'display');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get `Attempted to wrap undefined property display as function` it means that it can't replace a method that doesn't exist (yet).

If you actually get a value for `var spToast = Polymer.dom(spApp.root).querySelector('sp-toast')` in your test, and nothing about your test is going to give `display` a value, you could just set it, a la `spToast.display = function() {};` then you should be able to set a spy on it or what have you as needed.

Put it all together and you could have

```
test('it should validate the veteran', function() {
      var spApp = Polymer.dom(myEl.root).querySelector('sp-app');
      var spToast = Polymer.dom(spApp.root).querySelector('sp-toast');
      spToast.display = function() {};
      sinon.spy(spToast, 'display');
      // Trigger the side effect that would lead to `display` being called
      assert.equal(
        spToast.display.calledOnces,
        true
      );
});
```